# Can MediaPlayer preparation and Starting happen parallelly?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

As per the state diagram in android, MediaPLayer will start after prepare. I plan to implement an App which has to receive minimum content and player to be started with that. But player is waiting till the full content is received in preparation phase.

Ex: Total content length : 10kb, plan to start the player once the buffer reaches 2kb.i.e Player to wait till 2kb buffer is prepared and has to start the player.

Algorithm:
1.Start donwloading content from server
2.If buffer 2kb is prepared, start the player otherwise show spin progress to user (n/w delay)
3.repeat 2 till full content 10kb is arrived.

Can i achieve above algorithm with MediaPLayer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the MediaPlayer, as it completely controls the amount it buffers before indicating it's "prepared".

If you have PCM data available, you can use the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class for playback as you indicate. Otherwise if you can target Jelly Bean (and who can do that already!)
, you can use the new [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API.